# gcc warning "-WOverflow"

Tags: c++, gcc

please consider the following snippet of C++98 code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

template <typename T> T myLower() {
    if (std::numeric_limits<T>::is_integer) {
        return std::numeric_limits<T>::min();
    } else {
        return -std::numeric_limits<T>::max();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::cout << (int)myLower<uint8_t>() << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

When compiled with `g++ test.cpp && ./a.out` it works as expected: 0 is printed. But when compiled with any optimization (`-O1` upwards, `-Os` as well) the `-Woverflow` warning is emitted for the else-branch, which should only be there for floating-point numbers:

```
g++ test.cpp -Wall -O1 && ./a.out
test.cpp: In instantiation of ‘T myLower() [with T = unsigned char]’:
test.cpp:16:46:   required from here
test.cpp:9:16: warning: large integer implicitly truncated to unsigned type [-Woverflow]
         retval = -std::numeric_limits<T>::max();
         ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
0
```

This also fails for `uint16`, all other types work as they should. As far as I can see the `std::numeric_limits<uint8_t>::is_integer` should be a compile-time constant -- why is the else-branch compiled at all? The warning is not serious or did I miss something?

Ah, this happens in gcc5 and gcc6.

Thanks!

PS: I know that there will be `std::numeric_limits<>::lowest()` when the future will have arrived here...

Comment: Why are you surprised, with code relying on an overflow operation (albeit one with well defined results for unsigned types) that the compiler complains about an overflow operation?

Comment: I'm suprised because due to `is_integer` being a compile-time constant and true, the overflow shouldn't happen in the first place? And the overflow only "happens" for uint8_t and uint16_t, the bigger integers are fine...

Comment: Compilers are not required to optimise if/else when the test is a compile time constant.    If you want that behaviour, use a compile time construct (e.g. template specialisation)

Comment: Hm. Ok. Even on c++11, where `is_integer` is a `constexpr`, the else-branch is compiled...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that

```
if (std::numeric_limits<T>::is_integer)
```

Does not limit what `T` can be.  That means the `else` brance is always compiled and can trigger a warning if the operation would cause an overflow even if the branch is never reached.

If you had C++17 you could use `if constexpr` like

```
template <typename T> T myLower() {
    if constexpr (std::numeric_limits<T>::is_integer) {
        return std::numeric_limits<T>::min();
    } else {
        return -std::numeric_limits<T>::max();
    }
}
```

Which would only compile the `if` block or the `else` block depending on the `constexpr` condition.  Before C++17 you would have to use SFINAE to constrain the function to only compile if the template resolves.

Comment: Ah, well. Thanks. That settles it: C++17 is far far away from here ;-(